# get all link site in source html (python)

Tags: python, hyperlink, get

I want get all link in one web page ,this function only one link but need get all link ! of course i know need The One Ring true but i don't know use

i need get all link

```
def get_next_target(page):
start_link = page.find('<a href=')
start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
url = page[start_quote + 1:end_quote]
return url, end_quote
```

Comment: Please specify your needs clearly.

Comment: What do you mean by a "one ring"?

Comment: Use `HTMLParser` from package `html.parse`, and `urllib.parser.urljoin` if needed. Don't try to just search a substring or even a regexp, this won't work (well, not in all cases). Of course, if you have only one page to process, you can write a quick and dirty program, but it's not wise if you have many pages from different sources.

Comment: Just a few traps in your program: you assume quotes are always double quotes, but you may find single quotes in HTML files, or no quotes at all. And the string "<a href=" may appear in javascript code or in comments.

Answer (score 2):

This is where a HTML parser comes in handy. I recommend [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
def get_next_target(page)
    soup = BS(page)
    return soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) for that:

```
 import lxml.html

 def get_all_links(page):
     document = lxml.html.parse(page)
     return document.xpath("//a")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
site = urllib.urlopen('http://somehwere/over/the/rainbow.html')
site_data = site.read()
for link in BeautifulSoup(site_data, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print(link['href'])
```

Comment: Another way of doing it with "BS".